# How to get a list of unique Tokens in spaCy?

Tags: python, spacy

Is there an easy way to make a list of unique spacy tokens?

For example, I can get a list of word tokens like the following.

```
words = [w for w in list(doc) if w.is_alpha]
```

And "words" can consist of multiple tokens of the same text.  (e.g. I, am, what, I, am)
Is there a way to make "words" to have only unique tokens of text? (e.g. I, am, what)

I know `set()` makes a unique list but I don't think it works for tokens because its text data internally exists.
And I'm not trying to make a list of unique string texts, but a list of unique spacy tokens.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique token" if not unique strings? Every spaCy token is unique because it has its index in the doc. Also, don't use `list(doc)`, that doesn't do anything useful, just use `doc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you probably need to explain how you want to use this list to make something useful, but here's one way to get only the first spaCy token with a given string representation.

```
out = []
seen = set()
for word in doc:
    if word.text not in seen:
        out.append(word)
    seen.add(word.text)
# now out has "unique" tokens
```